# Making columns out of row values

Tags: r, tidyverse

I assume that there are already some answers on this topic. But I can´t find it.

I have this data:

```
library(tidyverse)
glimpse(samp)
Observations: 5
Variables: 2
$ business_id <chr> "--6MefnULPED_I942VcFNA", "--9e1ONYQuAa-CB_Rrw7Tw", "--...
$ Ambience    <chr> "romantic': False, 'intimate': False, 'classy': False, ...
```

I want to make the values before `:` as column name and the value after `:` as value e.g. `romatic` is a column name an the value is `False` or `True` (or NA if the respective ID has not the variable `romatic`.

This is what I tried:

```
samp %>%
  mutate(Ambience = strsplit(Ambience, ",")) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  separate(Ambience, into = c("key", "value")) %>%
  spread(key, value)
```

But I get this error:

```
Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), (10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17), (19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26), (28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35), (37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43) Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
```

Here is a dput:

```
structure(list(business_id = c("--6MefnULPED_I942VcFNA", "--9e1ONYQuAa-CB_Rrw7Tw", 
"--cjBEbXMI2obtaRHNSFrA", "--cZ6Hhc9F7VkKXxHMVZSQ", "--DaPTJW3-tB1vP-PfdTEg"
), Ambience = c("romantic': False, 'intimate': False, 'classy': False, 'hipster': False, 'touristy': False, 'trendy': False, 'upscale': False, 'casual': True}", 
"romantic': False, 'intimate': False, 'classy': True, 'hipster': False, 'divey': False, 'touristy': False, 'trendy': False, 'upscale': True, 'casual': False}", 
"romantic': False, 'intimate': False, 'classy': False, 'hipster': False, 'divey': False, 'touristy': False, 'trendy': False, 'upscale': False, 'casual': False}", 
"romantic': False, 'intimate': False, 'classy': False, 'hipster': False, 'divey': False, 'touristy': False, 'trendy': False, 'upscale': False, 'casual': True}", 
"romantic': False, 'intimate': False, 'classy': False, 'hipster': False, 'touristy': False, 'trendy': False, 'upscale': False, 'casual': True}"
)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little more tidying up your data seemed to do the trick. Specifically, removing `'` and `}`. There may also be a way to parse this with `jsonlite` but I didn't investigate that:

```
library(tidyverse)

samp %>%
  mutate(Ambience = strsplit(str_remove_all(Ambience, '[\'|}]'), ",")) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  mutate_at(vars(Ambience), str_trim) %>%
  separate(Ambience, into = c("key", "value")) %>%
  spread(key, value)

# A tibble: 5 x 10
  business_id            casual classy divey hipster intimate romantic touristy trendy upscale
  <chr>                  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> <chr>   <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>  <chr>  
1 --6MefnULPED_I942VcFNA True   False  NA    False   False    False    False    False  False  
2 --9e1ONYQuAa-CB_Rrw7Tw False  True   False False   False    False    False    False  True   
3 --cjBEbXMI2obtaRHNSFrA False  False  False False   False    False    False    False  False  
4 --cZ6Hhc9F7VkKXxHMVZSQ True   False  False False   False    False    False    False  False  
5 --DaPTJW3-tB1vP-PfdTEg True   False  NA    False   False    False    False    False  False
```

you can always use the `fill = FALSE` argument to `spread` if you want to assume `NA` is `FALSE`.